# Java sort ArrayList using bubblesort

Tags: java, sorting

I have been working on this for the past 5 hours. For some reason I am not getting the result I am looking for. The method is supposed to sort an `ArrayList` of items by quantity using bubble sort. Not sure if I am making a mistake but it seems to only sort the first few items and just lists the rest as they are and not in order.
Here is the code:

```java
public static void bubblesrt(ArrayList<Drinks> list)
{
    Drink temp;
    if (list.size()>1) // check if the number of orders is larger than 1
    {
        for (int x=0; x<list.size(); x++) // bubble sort outer loop
        {
            for (int i=0; i < list.size()-i; i++) {
                if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i+1)) > 0)
                {
                    temp = list.get(i);
                    list.set(i,list.get(i+1) );
                    list.set(i+1, temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the `compareTo()` method which is located in a `Drinks class`

```java
public int compareTo(Drinks z) 
{
    int res=0;
    if (quantity < z.quantity) {res = -1;}
    if (quantity > z.quantity) {res = 1;}
    return res;
}
```

How do I make this work as intended?

Comment: add homework tag if it's for a homework

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using [`Arrays.sort`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29)?

Comment: And if it isn't homework you shouldn't be using bubblesort at all, and other case you shouldn't be sorting an ArrayList, you should be sorting the underlying array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing

```
list.add(i,list.get(i+1) );
```

to

```
list.set(i,list.get(i+1) );
```

and

```
for (int i=0; i < list.size()-i; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i=0; i < list.size() - x - 1; i++)
```

Comment: correct, that was just a bad try. I will correct that. Like I said Very tired of staring at it for the past 5 hours

Comment: what about: for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) ?

Comment: Same thing. probably because i am comparing with the next one and there is no next one at the end of the list

Comment: yea sorry, `for (int i=0; i < list.size()-1; i++)` should give the right answer.

Comment: wow. that is just sad. all I had to do was change to 1. thanks. probably already tried that before but when you have worked for 10 hours and try to do this all night the screen is not very clear. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You have this line:

```
list.add(i,list.get(i+1) )
```

Should be:

```
list.set(i,list.get(i+1) )
```