# How do I Sort the names in a Linked List?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I'm trying to make a bank record that keeps on repeating until the user enters the command Q to quit. My while loop looks fine however it repeats only two times then it stops. Also I'm trying to write a printlist that organizes the names according to the last name. I tried printing it according to last name but it doesn't print according to last name.

My main class code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){     
    LinkedList<Customer2> bankRecords = new LinkedList<>(); 
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Command");
    String x=input.nextLine();


    while(true){
        if(x.equals("a")){
            if(bankRecords.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("Records are empty");
                System.out.println("Enter a command");
                x=input.nextLine();

            }else {
                printList(bankRecords);

                System.out.println("a  Show all records");
                System.out.println("r  Remove the current record");
                System.out.println("f  Change the first name in the current record");
                System.out.println("l  Change the last name in the current record");
                System.out.println("n  Add a new record");
                System.out.println("d  Add a deposit to the current record");
                System.out.println("w  Make a withdrawal from the current record");
                System.out.println("s Select a record from the record list to become the current record");
                System.out.println("Enter a command");
            }
        }

        if(x.equals("r")){
            bankRecords.removeLast();
            System.out.println("a  Show all records");
            System.out.println("r  Remove the current record");
            System.out.println("f  Change the first name in the current record");
            System.out.println("l  Change the last name in the current record");
            System.out.println("n  Add a new record");
            System.out.println("d  Add a deposit to the current record");
            System.out.println("w  Make a withdrawal from the current record");
            System.out.println("s Select a record from the record list to become the current record");
            System.out.println("Enter a command");
            x=input.nextLine();
        }
        if (x.equals("f")) {
            Customer2 currentRecord = bankRecords.getLast();
            System.out.print("Enter Firstname: ");
            String fname=input.nextLine();
            currentRecord.setFirstName(fname);
            currentRecord.menu();
            System.out.println("Enter a command");
            x=input.nextLine();

        }
        if (x.equals("l")) {
            Customer2 currentRecord = bankRecords.getLast();
            System.out.print("Enter Last Name: ");
            String lname=input.nextLine();
            currentRecord.setLastName(lname);
            currentRecord.menu();
            System.out.println("Enter a command");
            x=input.nextLine();
        }
        if(x.equals("d")){
            Customer2 currentRecord = bankRecords.getLast();
            System.out.print("Enter deposited amount");
            int deposit=input.nextInt();
            currentRecord.deposit(deposit);
            currentRecord.menu();
            System.out.println("Enter a command");
            x=input.nextLine();

        }
        if(x.equals("w")){
            Customer2 currentRecord = bankRecords.getLast();
            System.out.print("Enter Withdrawn amount");
            int withdraw=input.nextInt();
            currentRecord.withdraw(withdraw);
            currentRecord.menu();
            System.out.println("Enter a command");
            x=input.nextLine();

        }

        if(x.equals("n")){
            System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
            String name=input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Last name");
            String lname=input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Balance:");
            int balance=input.nextInt();
            bankRecords.add(new Customer2(name, lname, balance));
            System.out.println("a  Show all records");
            System.out.println("r  Remove the current record");
            System.out.println("f  Change the first name in the current record");
            System.out.println("l  Change the last name in the current record");
            System.out.println("n  Add a new record");
            System.out.println("d  Add a deposit to the current record");
            System.out.println("w  Make a withdrawal from the current record");
            System.out.println("s Select a record from the record list to become the current record");
            System.out.println("Enter a command");
            x=input.nextLine();

        }
        if(x.equals("q")){
            return;
        }
        if(x.equals("s")){
            System.out.println("Enter first name");
            String fname=input.nextLine();
            for(int i=0;i<bankRecords.size();i++){
                if(bankRecords.contains(fname)){
                    Customer2 cur=bankRecords.getLast();
                }}}}}
public static void printList(LinkedList<Customer2> list) {

    for (Customer2 data : list) {

        System.out.println(data.getFirstName()+"\t"+data.getLastName()+"\t"+data.getAccountBalance());

    }

}
```

My second class:

```
public class Customer2 {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int accountBalance;
    public int total=0;
    public Customer2(String fName, String lName, int balance){
        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
        accountBalance = balance;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String newFirstName){
        firstName = newFirstName;
        }
        public void setLastName(String newLastName){
        lastName = newLastName;
        }
    public String getFirstName() {

    return firstName;

    }

    public String getLastName() {

    return lastName;

    }



    public double getAccountBalance() {

    return accountBalance;

    }
    public void withdraw(int amount){
        total=accountBalance-amount;
        accountBalance=total;

    }
    public void deposit(int amount){
        total=accountBalance+amount;
        accountBalance=total;
    }



    public void menu(){

            System.out.println("a  Show all records");
            System.out.println("r  Remove the current record");
            System.out.println("f  Change the first name in the current record");
            System.out.println("l  Change the last name in the current record");
            System.out.println("n  Add a new record");
            System.out.println("d  Add a deposit to the current record");
            System.out.println("w  Make a withdrawal from the current record");
            System.out.println("s Select a record from the record list to become the current record");
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"I tried printing it according to last name"* Where?

Comment: I thought it would print it according to lastname

Comment: Would you mind posting a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first part is very messy and hard to understand. Its not even running for two cycles, my be for a particular case it ran to your pc. If you can clear the code and make it understandable then its possible to answer. For the second part, you required a sorted list based on lastname. For that, you required to implements Comparable to your Customer2 class.

```
public class Customer2 implements Comparable<Customer2>{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int accountBalance;
    public int total=0;
    public Customer2(String fName, String lName, int balance){
        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
        accountBalance = balance;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String newFirstName){
        firstName = newFirstName;
        }
        public void setLastName(String newLastName){
        lastName = newLastName;
        }
    public String getFirstName() {

    return firstName;

    }

    public String getLastName() {

    return lastName;

    }



    public double getAccountBalance() {

    return accountBalance;

    }
    public void withdraw(int amount){
        total=accountBalance-amount;
        accountBalance=total;

    }
    public void deposit(int amount){
        total=accountBalance+amount;
        accountBalance=total;
    }



    public void menu(){

            System.out.println("a  Show all records");
            System.out.println("r  Remove the current record");
            System.out.println("f  Change the first name in the current record");
            System.out.println("l  Change the last name in the current record");
            System.out.println("n  Add a new record");
            System.out.println("d  Add a deposit to the current record");
            System.out.println("w  Make a withdrawal from the current record");
            System.out.println("s Select a record from the record list to become the current record");
        }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Customer2 o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return o.lastName.compareTo(lastName);

    }
    }
```

Then, in your main class, you can sort the list using Collection. I have also attached the modified part here

```
public static void printList(LinkedList<Customer2> list) {

    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println(list);

}
```

Comment: I don't want to use collection. Is it possible to do without it. Also my while loop is not working even though I don't see anythign wrong with ti.

Comment: If you want to use your own sorting algorithm to sort, then you can follow this guideline http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774168/sorting-objects-in-an-arraylist-without-using-collections-sort